# Flutter Connectivity_plus with Linux Ubuntu on VM with VM VirtualBox

Tags: linux, flutter, virtualbox, connectivity

i use a notifier to check the connectivity.

```
class ConnectivityStatusNotifier extends StateNotifier<ConnectivityStatus> {
  ConnectivityStatusNotifier() : super(ConnectivityStatus.isDisconnected) {
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen(
      (ConnectivityResult result) {
        final newState = result.toConnectivityStatus;
        if (newState != state) {
          state = newState;
        }
      },
    );
  }
  StreamController<ConnectivityResult> controller =
      StreamController<ConnectivityResult>();
}
```

it works with windows, ios, macos, android platforms. But with Virtualized Linux on Windows computer, the result of connectivity is `none`

i think issue comes from my configuration of linux in the VM.
What is your advice ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before. I had a cloud Ubuntu VM in Azure. I installed the network manager.

Please run:

```
sudo snap install network-manager network-manager
```

Then, please restart the VM.

PS: Depending on your flutter project , you may also need to run

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub cache clean -f
flutter clean
```